# to change multiple space in text file into a $ sign in python

Tags: python

I try to change the multiple spaces in text file into a $ sign .

I tried this it works and make all spaces 1 space but I need to read all the text file if find space more than 2 it convert it into $ sign

```
fin = open("data.txt", "rt")
fout = open("out.txt", "wt")

for line in fin:
    fout.write(' '.join(line.split()))
    
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression like  `{2,}` (note the leading space) to find 2 or more spaces and `re.sub` those with `$`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "string with spaces  and  double  and   more    spaces"
>>> re.sub(" {2,}", "$", s)
'string with spaces$and$double$and$more$spaces'
```

If you want to replace them with an equal number of `$`, you can use `re.sub` with a callback:

```
>>> re.sub(" {2,}", lambda m: "$" * len(m.group()), s)
'string with spaces$$and$$double$$and$$$more$$$$spaces'
```

Applied to your code, the following should work fine (using the first version):

```
for line in fin:
    fout.write(re.sub(" {2,}", "$", line))
```

Comment: it works perfectly but how I implement it to do same thing on file .

Comment: @DoomraiqRaiq Just put the `re.sub(...)` into your `fout.write(...)` instead of the `' '.join(...)`

Comment: I did what you said but when I change fin instead of s to read from the file it gives me error    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object.  @tobias_k

Comment: @DoomraiqRaiq Do not pass the file as a whole but individual lines; see my edit.

Comment: it works with the some spaces and some are left as it is. in line number 1 everything perfect but other lines only the last space is changed into $ but the first space not. @tobias_k

Comment: @DoomraiqRaiq Well, it should definitely replace all groups of two or more spaces, not just the last. Sure those are actually (regular) spaces and not other kind of whitespace? You may try `\s{2,}` instead.

Comment: same thing friend @tobias_k

Comment: find that if I change the start of the line to word instead of number it works perfectly , but I have a number iat the beginning of each line . what you code work with the first number and ignore the space after the next number . does this help

Comment: @DoomraiqRaiq Please add an excerpt of the input file, or some equivalent input yielding the same problems, to your question.

Comment: 1 (3space) what is your name? (4space) MY name is second line start with number 2 (3spaces) Question( 4 spaces) answer and so on @tobias_k

Comment: check this plz https://repl.it/join/zfxsbbmi-nomatter  @tobias_k

Comment: Can't login to that, but your example works perfectly fine for me. Please copy-paste (!) a short example to the question itself (using the "edit" button); it might be that the spaces themselves are "wrong", e.g. some sort of "exotic" spaces.

Comment: anyway thank you very much for your help